# Strings in Python with [ [...] ]

Tags: python, string

I have a string which is represented in this format:

```
[[u'This is a string']], what does this mean??
```

How can I turn this into:

```
[u'This is a string']
```

or

```
['This is a string']
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> data = [[u'This is a string']]
>>> data[0][0]
u'This is a string'
```

The `u'...'` prefix means unicode

```
>>> print data[0][0]
This is a string
```

and it works perfectly fine, leave it like that. However for educational purposes this is how you convert it back to a normal Python 2.7 `str`

```
>>> str(data[0][0])
'This is a string'
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It answers the question perfectly.

Comment: @Rapptz Agreed, it's being balanced out though.

Comment: @jamylak So `data` isn't a string, its a string of strings?

Comment: `data` is a list (written `[...]`). The list contains one element, which is also a list (`[[...]]`). The inner list contains a unicode string (`u'This is a string'`). You can get the i'th element of a list by typing `l[i]`, so `data[0]` gives the inner list, and `data[0][0]` gives the string inside that.

Comment: Under which circumstances when I do `print data[0][0]` will I get `[`?

Comment: @JamesHallen You haven't explained what your data is and why it is stored like this, In your example `data[0][0]` will always be a string, does the data structure change?

Comment: I think I understand why that happened. I parsed a html tag into this variable `data` and then I used `str(data)` this is where I was wrong

Answer (score 6):

Well, you have a list in a list, and the inner list contains a single string. So:

```
x = [[u'This is a string']]
print x[0]      # first element of the outer list will be the inner list
print x[0][0]   # first element of the inner list is the string
```

Answer (score 2):

It's inside a list, inside a list.

To access it:

```
 [[u'This is a string']][0]
```

If you want the string:

```
[[u'This is a string']][0][0]
```

Comment: Posted hastily! Fixed :)